# Upgrade an overpass layer code to use react-leaflet v2

Tags: leaflet, react-leaflet, overpass-api

The question [Leaflet plugin only working when geolocation is enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40776256/leaflet-plugin-only-working-when-geolocation-is-enabled) had a nice wrapping of the OverpassLayer OSM for react-leaflet. Unfortunately, it only works for react-leaflet v1.

```
import { LayerGroup } from "react-leaflet";
import L from "leaflet";
import OverPassLayer from "leaflet-overpass-layer";

export default class OverpassLayer extends LayerGroup {
  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    console.log(nextProps.key);
    console.log("OverpassLayer receiving props");
    const query = "("
      + "node[\"amenity\"]({{bbox}});"
      + "way[\"amenity\"]({{bbox}});"
      + "relation[\"amenity\"]({{bbox}});"
      + ");"
      + "out body;"
      + ">;"
      + "out skel qt;";

    const opl = new L.OverPassLayer({
      "query": query,
      "endPoint": "https://overpass-api.de/api/",
    });
    nextProps.map.addLayer(opl);
  }
}
```

With v2, it doesn't work, ending with the error:

> TypeError: Super expression must either be null or a function

Any idea on how to update this code to v2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for everything in react-leaflet v2, we need to reimplement the intermediate class (`LayerGroup`) as well:

```
// @flow

import LeafletOverPassLayer from "leaflet-overpass-layer";

import { withLeaflet, MapLayer } from "react-leaflet";
import type { MapLayerProps } from "react-leaflet";

type LeafletElement = LeafletOverPassLayer;
type Props = MapLayerProps;

class OverPassLayer extends MapLayer<LeafletElement, Props> {
  createLeafletElement(props: Props): LeafletElement {
    const el = new LeafletOverPassLayer({
      query: "("
        + "node[\"amenity\"]({{bbox}});"
        + "way[\"amenity\"]({{bbox}});"
        + "relation[\"amenity\"]({{bbox}});"
        + ");"
        + "out body;"
        + ">;"
        + "out skel qt;",
      endpoint: "https://overpass-api.de/api/",
      minZoomIndicatorEnabled: false,
    }, this.getOptions(props));
    this.contextValue = { ...props.leaflet, layerContainer: el };
    return el;
  }
}

export default withLeaflet<Props, OverPassLayer>(OverPassLayer);
```

It's basically copy/paste + adding the overpass information. Here we display all amenities as a red circle.

Removed the zoom indicator as it seems to be missing an `onRemove` method.

Answer (score 0):

V2 of react-leaflet completely breaks the ability to extend many components. I raised an issue about this a while ago:
https://github.com/PaulLeCam/react-leaflet/issues/506

This is an intentional design choice by the library's author (a choice that I wholeheartedly disagree with but that's a moot point)

Read through that Github thread and if you have further questions just ask :)

Comment: I saw the discussion indeed, I have trouble understanding the decision as well (I also have trouble understanding the usage of yet another JS framework with flow and other stuff like that, where you don't even know what's the object the method operates on... I struggled with the different `this`).